# me muestra un error Advertencia : PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: número de parámetro no válido: el parámetro no se definió

Tags: php

Código Modificado de texto plano  a script para mayor referencia

me muestra un error Advertencia : PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: número de parámetro no válido: el parámetro no se definió

```
<?php        
        session_start();
        require 'database.php';        
    
        if (!empty($_POST['Codigo']) && !empty($_POST['Contraseña'])) {
            $sql = array( "INSERT INTO usuarios (Codigo, Contraseña) VALUES(:Codigo, :Contraseña)");
            $stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Codigo',$_POST['Codigo']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Contraseña',$_POST['Contraseña']);
    
            $message = '';
    
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $message=' HA SIDO CREADO UN USUARIO';
        } else {
            $message = 'HA OCURRIDO UN ERROR';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué la consulta, `$sql`, está dentro de un array? Si lo dejas como string debería funcionar. Mira los ejemplos en [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que el carácter ñ esta generando el error, uno de los conceptos básicos de programación es evitar lo menos posible caracteres especiales.valida tanto en la BD como en las variables.

Comment: Muy acertada tu observacion @pperez  yo ni habia notado la ñ :(

Comment: @Cesarin la ñ muchas da tanto problema como que falte el ";",  si se puede trabajar con estos caracteres pero necesitamos estandarizar todos los procesos por ejemplo en php hay opciones para caracteres especiales [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ucwords.php).